# WPF - Clearing only certain Resource Dictionaries

Tags: wpf, resources, themes

I am applying "themes" to my WPF app by clearing all merged dictionaries (Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear()) and new ones based on the selected theme. 
 
Instead of clearing all dictionaries, I would like to clear only certain "theme-related" dictionaries, leaving others still loaded. How can I do that? I didn't find a way to differentiate dictionaries when iterating though them...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're doing the merging at the `Application` level, otherwise you could just introduce an intermediate control whose only job is to host the theme dictionaries. That being the case, I would suggest using a multi-tiered approach whereby the first merged dictionary houses all theme-related dictionaries:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- all application level resources -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- theme-related resources -->
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <!-- merge in theme-related dictionaries here -->
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <!-- merge in other application-level dictionaries here -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- other resources -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Foo">Black</SolidColorBrush>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now you can target only theme-related resources with code like this:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0].Clear();
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0].Add(...);
```

Comment: Is there a way to give a resource dictionary a name so you can search for it rather than hard code it as the first one? Or is this considered an acceptable coupling between the XAML and code?